# How to get Reviews and Transmittals by project from Autodesk Forge API?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-bim360

I tried to find a method to get reviews and transmittals and didn't find it in BIM360 API or Data Management API. Is it possible to get it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No API for Reviews and Transmittals exposed for BIM 360 at this time. There is a wish for Review API:

ALEX-37150: “API wish: expose Docs Review API”

We would be interested in knowing what kind of workflow you are trying to accomplish with API. It might help the product team to prioritize their work. If you want to catch the activities change, you may be able to find in activities log, which we are hoping to release near future. (Although we are always cautious to say this till we see it.)

Comment: Hi, any update on exposing the transmittal API? My company is working on extracting information about document upload and version date vs when it was issued using the transmittal.

Comment: No update for transmittals API. Sorry. (We have Reviews in private beta now.)  
In a mean time, I wonder if Data Connecter API can be of any use as a workaround. 

https://developer.api.autodesk.com/data-connector/v1/doc/schema?name=transmittals&format=html

https://aps.autodesk.com/blog/data-connector-schema-now-public-endpoints

Would you like to take a look in case it includes the information you can use?

Comment: Thank you, its a bit of legwork but it seems like it would work for my use case.