# Fetch the review information from BIM 360 using Forge APIs

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am trying to get the data present under the 'Reviews' tab under Document Management in BIM 360. Is there an exposed endpoint that can fetch those details?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no API available for the Reviews at this moment, but there is a wish for Review API: `ALEX-37150: “API wish: expose Docs Review API”`.

In addition, we would be interested in knowing what kind of workflow you are trying to accomplish with API. It might help the product team to prioritize their work. If it cannot be posted publicly, please reach out to `forge[DOT]help[AT]autodesk[DOT]com`.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64392350/7745569

Comment: Thanks Eason for your response. I will reach out to the team as mentioned by you.